# Are $\{\frac{1}{n}|n∈\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Would anyone be able to explain why not?

I feel like you can show it using sequences, but I'm not sure how.

Usual metric of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: One has a limit point, the other doesn't.

Comment: Just edited. They should both be metric spaces.

Comment: It depends on the topology. If they both have discrete topology, then any bijection will do, since any function from a set with the discrete topology to the another set also with  discrete topology is continuous.

Comment: sorry for deleting. just wanted to be sure i was correct before saying that :)

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is not compact and $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$ is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intuition is in the comments:

> One has a limit point, the other doesn't

So let's run with this and write a proof by contradiction: We'll show that any bijection $$h: \bigg\{\frac{1}{n}\ \bigg|\ n=1,2,\ldots\bigg\}\cup\{0\} \to \mathbb{Z}$$ cannot be continuous. We will apply the intuition by focusing on the limit point $0$ and its image under $h$.

For convenience denote $X = \bigg\{\frac{1}{n}\ \bigg|\ n=1,2,\ldots\bigg\}$.

Let $p = h(0)$. The set $\{p\}$ is open in $\mathbb{Z}$. But its preimage $h^{-1}(\{p\}) = \{0\}$ is *not* open in $X$ because every open set of $X$ that contains $0$ also contains at least one other point.

Since a homeomorphism is, in particular, a continuous bijection, there is no homeomorphism between $X$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

---

**Bonus material**

An *accumulation point* of a topological space $X$ is a point $p\in X$ such that every open set $U$ containing $p$ also contains at least one other point of $X$, that is, for every open $U\ni p$ there exists $q\in X$ with $q\neq p$ and $q\in U$.

Exercise 1: Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and let $f:X\to Y$ be continuous and injective. Show that if $p\in X$ is an accumulation point of $X$, then $f(p)$ is an accumulation point of $Y$.

Exercise 2: Apply Exercise 1 to your question :)

Comment: Oh, now I see it. I was a bit confused by the intuition, didn't get the relationship. Great answer, thank you.

Comment: The Bonus material is deep and excellent!!! @Neal

Comment: Exercise 1 is false in general, beware!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma how bout now?

Comment: @Neal with injective added it’s OK.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you for the catch :)

Answer (score 2):

$0$ is a limit point in the first set.  But $\mathbb Z $ has none.

Comment: Would you be able to expand on that? I'm not sure I see the relationship between limit points and homeomorphisms as bijective, continuous functions with continuous inverse.

Comment: Well, using say the limit point definition of continuity,  we easily get a contradiction.

Comment: Another way: one space is discrete, the other isn't.   The point $\{0\} $ isn't open in the first space.